# jQUERY - accordion active state asp.net code behind

Tags: asp.net, jquery

Can anyone inform me how to maintain the jquery accordion active state panel when changing pages. Ideally i would like to change in the code-behind however really happy to just get it working.

developing in asp.net 3.5

Hope this helps

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example [here](http://pastebin.me/pastebin/_design/pastebin.me/_show/raw/7e9a706bada549281fd1379b46722145). If you select one of the accordion headers then refresh the page the last accordian panel you clicked is opened by default

I see this as a pure client responsibility. I would store the information in a cookie [plugin here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie) which you can read and pass to the accordion constructor.
I would prefer this over passing values to and from the server for no real benefit.

Something along these lines

```
//get persisted active accoridan index
var activeIndex  = $.cookie('accordianActiveIndex');

//guard code here to check you have a valid activeIndex...

$('.selector').accordion({
       active: activeIndex,
       change: function(event, ui) { 
           //set cookie here to new active header (index)
           $.cookie('accordianActiveIndex', ui.newHeader.prevAll().length)
      }
});
```

Comment: should i simply copy and paste this below my function for the accordion. Sorry this is my first time using jquery. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: First you will need to download and include the plugin script. The you could give it a try but it is very much psuedo code..!

Comment: i have downloaded the lpugin and pasted in the code supplied, no luck.
can you help ?

Comment: Is the selector correct? Note I just used the generic .selector.
A link to the page or a copy of the code you have would help...

Comment: i have been trying this out on just the demo accordion. please see code below: 

<div id="accordion">
   <div>
    <h3><a href="#">First</a></h3>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
   </div>
   <div>
    <h3><a href="#">Second</a></h3>
    <div>Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh.</div>
   </div>
   <div>
    <h3><a href="#">Third</a></h3>
    <div>Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis.</div>
   </div>
  </div>

i simply changed the .selector to #accordion and added: header: "h3",

can you help ? Thanks

Comment: I also found this example to be very useful to my same issue!

Comment: To get this to work I had to add "activeIndex = parseInt(activeIndex, 10);" (posted below with credit to redsquare)

Comment: I had to add to add a filter to prevAll() to get it to work properly. It seems it was pick up the `<div>` from the accordion content. This is what worked for me `$.cookie('accordianActiveIndex', ui.newHeader.prevAll('h3').length);`

Answer (score 2):

For anyone with a similar problem getting cookies to work with jQuery UI Accordion, I've solved it by adding one line to [redsquare's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6440/redsquare) code.

The cookie value `activeIndex` needs to be parsed as an integer:

```
//get persisted active accoridan index
var activeIndex  = $.cookie('accordianActiveIndex');
activeIndex = parseInt(activeIndex, 10);

//guard code here to check you have a valid activeIndex...

$('.selector').accordion({
       active: activeIndex,
       change: function(event, ui) { 
           //set cookie here to new active header (index)
           $.cookie('accordianActiveIndex', ui.newHeader.prevAll().length)
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

And here's another way to save UI Accordion state using the **cookie.js** plugin:

[(source)](http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/3613)

```
var accordion = $("#accordion");
var index = $.cookie("accordion");
var active;
if (index !== null) {
    active = accordion.find("h3:eq(" + index + ")");
} else {
    active = 0
}
accordion.accordion({
    header: "h3",
    event: "click hoverintent",
    active: active,
    change: function(event, ui) {
        var index = $(this).find("h3").index ( ui.newHeader[0] );
        $.cookie("accordion", index, {
            path: "/"
        });
    },
    autoHeight: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I Just use

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({ navigation: true });
```

that maintains the status of the selected option